# PayPal Express integration isn't working when I enable the term and condition

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, paypal-express

I am using Magento ver. 2.1.9

I have integrated with PayPal express.but when I enable term and condition, the PayPal is not working.

please give me a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this issue fix on this extension and 
 its only a fix for paypal module which is a magento core module

[this is a module to fix the broken paypal payment in magento2](https://github.com/CopeX/PaypalFix)

Comment: this is not working on my website.

Comment: Means you have installed this extension?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the extension.

Comment: working or not?

Comment: Not working on my website

Comment: above extension working for all over which error face when this extension use?

Comment: no error but, it also not works for my side

Answer (score 0):

there is some issue with "terms and condition" setting in Magento-backend without selecting the "terms and condition" you can't move further please check